# What endpoint to use to identify deposits as transactions using PLaid?

Tags: plaid

I'm using the /transactions/get endpoint to get transactions but I noticed it only gets "spending transactions". is there a way identify transactions in my account that were deposits?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`/transactions/get` retrieves all transactions, including deposits. If you're seeing a situation where the endpoint is not returning deposits and you've verified that the issue isn't how you're calling the API (for example, accidentally using a date range that excludes the deposits you're looking for), you should try the [missing transactions troubleshooting guide](https://plaid.com/docs/transactions/troubleshooting/#missing-transactions) and file a support ticket if necessary.

Comment: I know I can check the payment_channel == other, but other can also be fees, how can I clearly identity deposits? do I need to consider only the negative amounts in the amount field?

Comment: Yes, negative amounts will be credits (which are almost always deposits).